# Applying modern control systems to real mechanical engineering problems

Tags: vibration

My aim was to damp the vibration of a stepper motor ( Nema 8 ) using only spring systems. I have taken modern control course and I wanted to apply it here.

So I first analyzed my open loop system and found it to be highly unstable. I then used Ackermans formula to find State feedback $K$ after checking it to be controllable and observable, and I found $K$. I plugged my $K$ in Matlab and the solution becomes perfect.

THE PROBLEM:

Now what is this magical number (matrix) $K$ I need to insert in my system to make this work? What is the value of $K$ in real life? What does $K$ represent?

Comment: Can you add the equations of your system and/or controller? A diagram would be nice too.